# Solving "loader constraints violated when linking [...] class" error in Java

Tags: java, validation, myfaces

I am new to Java and experiencing problems understanding exceptions thrown by the framework.

Right now, I am trying to implement a regular expression validator into an application consisting of Java 5 EE with myFaces 1.2 and Tobago running in an apache tomcat 5.5.

I followed a couple of tutorials (including the Java 5 EE tut from SUN) and came pretty far. However, when calling my jsp, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraints violated when linking javax/faces/validator/Validator class
```

Can anyone explain to me what I need to do to solve this problem?

So far, it seems as if MyFaces 1.1.7 has a version conflict to TomCat 5.5. Both contain javax.* packages (one of them namely javax.faces.validator). The validator class has a different version in the packages. The corresponding MyFaces library is called myfaces-api-1.1.7.jar and the TomCat library is called javaee.jar.

The included javax packages in the myfaces lib is a subset of the packages from within the javaee lib. However... I cannot skip any of both, because the project will fail to start then.

Any tipps?

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly caused by your application having its own copy of `Validator` (in one of its JAR files), and this is clashing with the server's own copy. Something this can cause a `LinkageError`.

Find out which of your WAR or EAR's JAR files contains that, and remove it (along with the rest of the `javax.faces` classes).

Comment: I believe I found the source of the exception, however, I don't know how to solve this problem.
Under Libraries in Eclipse, I can see Apache Tomcat v5.5 with the library javaee.jar containing a lot of javax packages including the javax.faces.validator package. Additionally, I can see JSF MyFaces 1.1 with the library myfaces-api-1.1.7.jar containing a couple of javax packages also including the javax.faces.validator package.

How do I solve this, as I believe I need both libraries and cannot remove one without breaking my project?

Comment: If Tomcat has the javax.faces as part of its libraries, then it should also include a full implementation, and your application doesn't need myfaces-api-1.1.7.jar at all

Comment: Removing myfaces-api-1.1.7.jar immediately results in an UnsupportedOperationException when the webapp is started:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException / javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getELContext(FacesContext.java:137)

Comment: hmm, ok looks like the JSF in Tomcat is a different version to the JSF in your application. You might have to repack myfaces-api-1.1.7.jar, removing the jabax classes, but keeping everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classpath problem. Check your classpath for two jars with conflicting versions (both containing the `javax.faces.validator.Validator` class)

---

According to the MyFaces homepage. [Tomcat Config: Tomcat 5.5.x](http://myfaces.apache.org/core11/tomcat.html)

> Some users have reported problems when
>   using MyFaces with Tomcat 5.5.x. Here
>   is a short guide that will hopefully
>   help you not run into the same
>   problems :-)
>
> If your are using the binary version
>   of MyFaces: MyFaces is packaged so
>   that it works with **Tomcat 5.0.x** so
>   the **WEB-INF/lib/jsp-2.0.jar** and
>   **WEB-INF/lib/commons-el.jar** JAR files **must be removed** from your
>   WAR files (including the examples).
>
> If you are building from source: If
>   you want to build MyFaces from scratch
>   to work with Tomcat 5.5.x, you have to
>   set the property
>   tomcat.pre.5.5.version in the
>   $MYFACES_HOME/build/build.default.properties
>   file to the value false.

Comment: As commented in skaffman's reply, I found the jars: javaee.jar and myfaces-api-1.1.7.jar. I only dont know how to solve that conflict as I need both...

Comment: Check expanded answer maybe this applies to you

Comment: Under WEB-INF/lib I don't have jsp-2.0.jar nor commons-el.jar. However, I have another directory containing libs that are included in my project. The MyFaces directory contains a commons-el.jar file but no jsp-2.0.jar file. The included TomCat libraries contain a jsp-api.jar. However, what I don't understand is, neither commons nor jsp contain any of the javax.faces.validator packages.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've got two conflicting versions of the same library available on your classpath. For example, you might have a jar file in WEB-INF/lib that's already provided in TOMCAT_HOME/lib. (el-api.jar is a common culprit, but there are other possibilities.)